# change CSS visibility on click with either jQuery or something else

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a DIV that acts as a menu item and would like to show another div on hover.  by default, the second div (the one I want to show is: `visibility: hidden;`.  is it possible to change visibility on hover somehow without jQuery? and if its not, what would my jQuery code look like?

Comment: Is the second div inside the first div in the markup ?

Comment: Can you paste html here, for better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the second div (class second-div) to a child element of the first div (class first-div), then use:

```
.first-div:hover .second-div {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vEeMS/

If you are creating a navigation, I would recommend to use `display` instead of `visibility`. `display: none;` means that the element is not displayd on the page, `visibility: hidden;` means that the element is on the page, but you can't see it. This has the disadvantage that the user can click on an invisible link, and he can't mark text or click a button under the invisible div.

Comment: I think that's exactly it!  thanks... I'll try your code.

Comment: after changing some stuff around, it works. very simple code. thanks I didn't realize you can specify hover on a div and trigger another div like that.